# Absolute positioned SVG above a div element shows a gap in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

I've the problem, that with an absolute positioned SVG element, which should be displayed above a div element, a gap is shown in Firefox `71.0 (64-bit)`.

[image: Problem]

The following minimal example outlines the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
      html {
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 100%;
      }

      body > div {
        flex-grow: 1;
      }

      #special {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #FFF;
      }

      #special svg, #special div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 100%;
      }

      #special div {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Box one
    </div>
    <div id="special">
      <svg color="#6A4A3C" viewBox="0 0 100 2">
        <polygon
          points="0 0, 100 0, 100 2, 20 0, 0 2"
          transform="scale(1 -1) translate(0 -2) scale(-1 1) translate(-100 0)"
        ></polygon>
      </svg>
      <!--<div>
        Magic div
      </div>-->
      Box two
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can run test this code in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/efabh6g1/). When you increase or decrease the width the gap changes:

[image: Example]

I'm looking for a solution, which **doesn't** just push the SVG one pixel down, as it would look ugly where the divider touches the other div. Also increasing the height of one part and make it overlap brings difficulties as it's hard to include this overlap into the design of the website.

[image: Workaround issue]

With this overlap it's hard to center the content of the box above, so it doesn't look strange.

Oddly Chrome doesn't do that, but it does at the sides. How can I prevent this issues?

Comment: **comment1**: you have 2 `id="special"` **comment2**: I don't see the gap but please try to give the svg `display:block` or `inline-block`

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for pointing out my typo with the id in the closing tag. Please see the screenshots.

Comment: Draw the whole thing with SVG (or draw it all with HTML) as a single shape. antialiasing is always going to be an issue otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a different approach: border shapes with a `:before`...

SCSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
special-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
  background: #fff;
}

div + div {
  background: #000;
  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-left: 80vw #000 solid;
    border-right: 20vw #000 solid;
    border-top: 20px #fff solid;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

HTML (I simplified for clarity)

```
<special-box>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</special-box>
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/bstees/pen/OJPmmLR

Note: I had to use `vw` for width on the border size. If this needs to leave room on either side of other elements, this will need to be tweaked.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your SVG a bit and did a little hackery to remove the anti-aliasing by getting the two elements to overlap by one 1px (added a pixel to the SVG so the shape is preserved).

HTML

```
...
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 3">
  <polygon
    points="0 0, 80 2, 100 0, 100 3, 0 3"></polygon>
</svg>
...
```

CSS (tad hacky)

```
#special svg {
  ...
  bottom: calc(100% - 1px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm looking for a solution and not a workaround. This has side effects on the design. I've mentioned this in my question.

Comment: Yes, I should read the whole thing. You could use the SVG adjustments at the very least. May I ask what side effects you are seeing with the overlap?

Comment: Your solution doesn't have a side effect, because you increased the lower part of the shape accordingly. Chrome still has still an anti-aliasing problem at the sides, even though it's barely visible. As @Robert Longson mentioned, probably the only stress free solution is to draw the whole shape?

Comment: Try ```<polygon points="-1 0, 0 0, 80 2, 100 0, 101 0, 101 3, -1 3">``` I added a few points to extend the shape beyond it's box a pixel. I don't see the aa on my Chrome. Let us know if this does it.

Comment: The problem with this solution is now, that I have a gap between the content and the divider, even though it's not visible. It's impossible to figure out how much I have to push the divider down or up, because 1 unit of the svgs viewbox cannot be calculated? For me this is still a workaround and not a real solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it suits you, but I have read about this issue in other questions (cannot remember where). Firefox has these gaps that seem related to [anti-aliasing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering). If you add to your `css` this,

```
polygon{
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

You will eliminate the gap in a consistent way (meaning you get the same result as in other browsers). Unfortunately, that also means that your diagonal lines get uglier (also in a consistent way).